# Print column names along with the difference in output of two tables using shell script

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix, diff

I am trying to find out the difference between two tables in **unix**.

Here is the snippet of my shell script

```
sqlplus -s `echo $user`/`echo $password`@`echo $host`:`echo $port`/`echo $sid` @property.sql table1 table2 >1.table
sqlplus -s `echo $user`/`echo $password`@`echo $host`:`echo $port`/`echo $sid` @property.sql table2 table1 >2.table
..........................................
..........................................
diff -wy 1.table 2.table (here, option 'y' can be ommitted also)
```

**Property.sql**

```
SET ECHO ON
SET NEWPAGE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET WRAP ON
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TAB OFF
SET HEADING ON
SET LINESIZE 4000

select property_id ,endpoint,key,value,value1,value2 from &2 where property_id in (
select table1.property_id from
(SELECT property_id,KEY,value,endpoint FROM &2
MINUS
SELECT property_id,KEY,value,endpoint FROM &1)  
table1 left join &1 table2 on table1.property_id=table2.property_id) order by TO_NUMBER(property_id);
exit;
```

The above is printing me the difference.
I want the corresponding column names also to get printed. How to do that?

Comment: If you could `SET HEADING OFF` in the second SQL Call, heading will start appearing in diff as it will be present in the first file but not in second.

Comment: As an aside... why don't you do `sqlplus -s "${user}/${password}@${host}..."`

Comment: As an aside... why don't you use here documents sqlplus /nolog << EOF connect ${user}/${password}@${host} @property.sql table1 table2 EOF